# Is it possible to prove the absolute consistency of a theory by giving a finite model?

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

Most consistency results are relative, they say that if theory $T$ is consistent, then theory $T'$ is consistent. However, is it possible to prove the "absolute" consistency of a theory, by giving a finite (preferably a small finite) model? For example, the theories of groups and Boolean algebras are absolutely consistent, because there are small finite models for both of them. Has any book or paper or text talked about this notion of absolute consistency?

Comment: What do you mean by "absolute" here?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Presumably not relative to any (substantive) consistency hypotheses.

Comment: Finite models are the subject in [Finite model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_model_theory). Is this question about getting away from having to refer to a formal theory? Like if I have $1$ red stone and $1$ blue stone, and instantiate the $4$ rules of a mapping such that they behave like what's known as ${\mathbb Z}_2$, then in daily praxis I act as if it is ruled out that I would by some curious means end up concluding that the red stone $is$ the blue stone. Would you consider this a theory-less and hypothesis-less model validating the consistency of the theory of groups?

Comment: Maybe this isn't what you mean, but if our model of group theory has a small finite number of group elements, there are still a countably infinite number of logical statements which can be made about the group, and the model assigns true or false to each. Also we'll always depend on assuming the logical rules for constructing proofs, such as first order predicate logic, are consistent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It seems like you know that you can show a theory is consistent by giving a model (in particular, a finite model will do). After all, you give the examples of groups and boolean algebras. It's a very easy theorem (surely proven in every textbook on model theory) that any theory with a model is consistent. (If you want to be _very_ pedantic, it's consistent relative to the consistency of the metatheory). Regardless, since it seems like you know this, I'm not sure what your question is. Do you mind clarifying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with the premise that most consistency results are relative. I think there's a theory/meta-theory conflation going on here. Here are two standard examples of consistency results:

1. It's a theorem that if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, then $\mathsf{NBG}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)) is consistent. This consistency result is relative, since we're assuming consistency of a theory whose consistency we can't prove (assuming our meta-theory is like $\mathsf{ZFC}$ or weaker, we can't prove $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$, by Gödel). The usual way to prove this would be to take a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and produce from it a model of $\mathsf{NBG}$.
2. It's a theorem that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent. This consistency result is *not* relative. The usual way to prove this would be to point to a model of $\mathsf{PA}$ (like $\mathbb{N}$), which we can do without assuming consistency of any other theory.

Now, you might still say that the consistency of $\mathsf{PA}$ is not absolute, because it relies on believing in the *soundness* of the meta-theory (i.e., that the meta-theory doesn't prove anything false), or because not every meta-theory can carry out the proof (e.g., if $\mathsf{PA}$ is our meta-theory, we cannot carry out this proof - or any proof - of $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$, by Gödel). But if this is your view, then there are no absolute theorems whatsoever in mathematics! Proving a theorem always relies on meta-theoretic reasoning, and different meta-theories can always disagree about what reasoning is allowable.

Now, you might argue that certain "very concrete" facts are more "absolute" than $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$, like $1+1 = 2$ or "there is a prime number greater than $10$". Sure, I agree, but saying that every meta-theory should prove these facts just amounts to putting some reasonable minimum requirements on what should count as a meta-theory, like "the meta-theory should be sound and complete for such and such class of very concrete statements". That is, you want the meta-theory to at least contain some base very weak system, and then the "absolute" theorems will be the ones provable in that system.

So maybe a better framing of your question is: How weak can a meta-theory be and still carry out model-theoretic consistency proofs for theories with explicit finite models?

To prove, for example, that the theory of groups is consistent by exhibiting the trivial group as a model, our meta-theory needs to be able to (a) talk about strings of symbols and recognize proofs from finite theories, so as to even formulate $\mathrm{Con}(T)$, (b) define "model of $T$" (at least for models with a single element!) and recognize that the trivial group is a model of the group axioms, and (c) prove the soundness theorem (at least for models with a single element!) - that is, prove by induction on the length of proofs that nothing provable from the group axioms is false in the trivial group. I'm not an expert in weak theories of arithmetic, but all that can certainly be carried out in a very weak meta-theory, with just a little bit of induction.